# Cannot Create a Controller in MVC 6

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently creating an MVC 6 project (MVC Movies) and I wish to pull through the AspNetUsers to be displayed so I can later edit them.

I have created a AspNetUsers class with the following Code Inside:

```
namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class AspNetUsers
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But when I try to make a Controller (with Views) to utilize this, I am always met with the following Error:

[image: Error Code From Trying to create Controller.]

My Add Controller Menu has the following Data when i try to create it:

[image]

Am I missing something which is in turn preventing me from creating my Controller With Views?

Comment: you need to have a parameterless constructor in your datacontext - ApplicationDbContext

Comment: @Forlani Thanks for commenting, Since i have a public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; } for another Class i have added public DbSet<AspNetUSers> AspNetUSers{ get; set; } to 'ApplicationDbContext' - is this this what you meant? I'm relatively new to this so please excuse me if it is wrong.

Comment: As @Forlani said you need to create a parameterless/default constructor in your ApplicationDbContext  class